# apply function to a groupby object takes too long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe object which has ["time", "tag", "value", "id"] columns and I need to groupby them with "time" and "id". As a result I need a dataframe object has columns ["time","value","new_column"] and new_column value is a dictionary (key: tag, value: value).

I've tried to using apply method with creating new dictionary and generating new dataframe from it

```
    time_dict = dict()
    def append_to_dict(x):
        time_dict[x.iloc[0]["time"]] = [x[["tag", "value"]].set_index('tag')['value'].to_dict(), x["id"].values[0]]
    df.groupby(["_time"]).apply(lambda x: append_to_dict(x))
    table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(time_dict, orient='index', columns=["tag", "id"])
```

Is there an easy way to do it because it takes too long to process?

this is the df object

```
time                  tag   value   id
2022-02-01T08:14:33Z  tag1  value1  id1
2022-02-01T08:14:33Z  tag2  value2  id1
2022-02-01T09:16:33Z  tag3  value3  id2
```

expected output is

```
time                  id    new_column
2022-02-01T08:14:33Z  id1  {tag1:value1, tag2:value2}
2022-02-01T08:14:33Z  id2  {tag3:value3}
```

Comment: you should provide a minimal reproducible example of the input/expected output

Comment: FWIW, `apply(lambda x: append_to_dict(x))` is just `apply(append_to_dict)`

Comment: @mozway I added input and expected output

Comment: Does `df.drop_duplicates("id").assign(new_col=[dict(zip(gr.tag, gr.value)) for _, gr in df.groupby("time")])` gain you anything?

Comment: @MustafaAydın but drop_duplicates causes value lost

Comment: @kyo Yes but that's for keeping unique ID rows only. Note that the list comprehension still acts on the original frame `df`. I get your expected output with it.

Comment: I think because of drop_duplicates it gives ValueError, ```ValueError: Length of values (22464) does not match length of index (12)``` @MustafaAydın

Comment: Oh, we should drop-duplicate over `"time"` as it's the grouper, not `"id"` sorry... Does `df.drop_duplicates("time").assign(new_col=[dict(zip(gr.tag, gr.value)) for _, gr in df.groupby("time")])` work at all now? [only change is id -> time in dropdupes.] @kyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
(df.groupby(['time', 'id'])
   .apply(lambda g: g.set_index('tag')['value'].to_dict())
   .rename('new_column')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
                   time   id                            new_column
0  2022-02-01T08:14:33Z  id1  {'tag1': 'value1', 'tag2': 'value2'}
1  2022-02-01T09:16:33Z  id2                    {'tag3': 'value3'}
```

Comment: Thank you, you made it in a simpler way and this code is faster. However no matter what apply function is always slow because it works like for loop underneath. Just for curiosity is there any way without using the apply?

Comment: Well you have to loop at some point ;) Note that you are looping here on groups, not rows.

Comment: yeap you're right :)